# Javascript variable becomes true when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, input

I have some sort of shop. 1 bar with filters, 1 bar with items.
Filter bar has input field FROM and TO for prices
It looks like this

```
<input id="pricefrom" type="text" placeholder="Min" style="position:relative; float: left; width:100px;">
<input id="priceto" type="text" placeholder="Max" style="position:relative; float: right; width:100px;">
```

And script that handles input when user focuses out:

```
$("#pricefrom").focusout(function() {
    var from = $("#pricefrom").val();
    var to = $("#priceto").val();
    console.log("from: "+from);
    console.log("to: "+to);
    if(from > to){
        $('#pricefrom').val(to);
        from = to;
        console.log("from > to");
    }
    drawItems(from, to);
});
$("#priceto").focusout(function() {
    var from = $("#pricefrom").val();
    var to = $("#priceto").val();
    console.log("from: "+from);
    console.log("to: "+to);
    if(to < from){
        $('#priceto').val(from);
        to = from;
        console.log("to < from");
    }
    drawItems(from, to);
});
```

If user puts FROM price bigger than TO, is makes it even. input "150-50" => "150-150"

But it happens to work correctly only 1 time. Then for example it has "200-200" values. I put FROM price to correct 50 value. It logs "from: 50" "to: 200" "from > to" and makes FROM equal to 200. But its lower, how the hell (from > to) becomes true?

Sry for poor english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` returns strings, not numbers, so you're performing lexicographic comparisons, not numeric comparisons. The string `"50"` is greater than `"150"`.

Convert the values to numbers before you compare them.

```
var from = parseInt($("#pricefrom").val(), 10);
var to = parseInt($("#priceto").val(), 10);
```

Comment: Daaamn, of course it is. I've heard about it and forgot. I'm new to coding, so...
Worked like a charm. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a standard type joke from JavaScript. Compare two examples:

```
50 > 200; // gives false
"50" > "200"; // gives true, because, "5" greater then "2"
```

`.val()` returns a string, so you are comparing strings. Call `parseInt` before comparison, that should prevent from such errors:

```
var from = parseInt($("#pricefrom").val(), 10);
var to = parseInt($("#priceto").val(), 10);
```

P.S. And never forget about radix for `parseInt` (10 in our case). Otherwise, if there will be something like "023" in the input (a value, starting from 0), some browsers can understand it as an octal number.